# Should I be able to pass a NotesDocumentCollection in a sessionScope variable?

Tags: xpages

I have one page that does a NotesDatabase search and of course returns a collection.  I am storing that collection in a sessionScope variable and calling a page where I what ti display the results.

```
if ( collection1.getCount() == 0)
{
    displayErrorMsg("Your search returned zero results. Please try another search.",getClientId("title"), "Zero Results");
}
else
{

    sessionScope.put("searchResults",collection1);
    var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    extCont.redirect("xp_vwIssueSearchResults.xsp");

}
```

The page has a data table with the content of the scope variable as it's datasource:

```
sessionScope.get("searchResults");
```

When I call this page I get, NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled.

Should I be able to pass a NotesDocumentCollection in a sessionScope variable?  I have some thoughts on work arounds but it would sure be nice to pass the NotesDocumentCollection.

Comment: No, because Notes objects are not serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't keep Notes objects like views, documents, collections for a longer time. In general, you should work with Notes object in a way, that you save the data you're interested in somewhere and recycle (=destroy) the Notes objects right away. The reason is that the Domino server can't save the Notes objects for you between two request because Notes objects aren't serializable (serializable = ability to save objects on disk and restore them back to memory).

In your case, you could save

- the search query or
- the result values as an Array of Objects (JavaScript) or a List of Maps (Java) or
- the documentUniqueIDs of document collection's documents

in your sessionScope variable and use them in your redirected page.

Comment: Thanks Knut.   I did not think of saving the Doc IDs as one of my work arounds.  That is a great idea and I think that is how I will go.